# Bluetooth Headset PulseAudio No Sound

Tags: pulseaudio, manjaro, bluetooth

**EDIT: I found the answer later on my own, it's posted below**

I'm currently trying to use a bluetooth headset on a PC with Manjaro Linux. I have no issue connecting the headset, but once it's connected, there's no sound.

I think I've traced the error to PulseAudio, which shows this error when my headset is connected:

```
pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

However, I don't know what to do next. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

System Info:

```
cpu:
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz, 3442 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz, 3496 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz, 3484 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz, 3480 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz, 3457 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz, 3500 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz, 3471 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz, 3446 MHz
keyboard:
  /dev/input/event5    AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
  /dev/input/event22   Mi Bluetooth Neckband Earphones (AVRCP)
mouse:
  /dev/input/mice      Wacom CTL-6100 [Intuos (M)]
  /dev/input/mice      Pixart Imaging Optical Mouse
  /dev/input/mice      SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
graphics card:
                       nVidia GP104BM [GeForce GTX 1070 Mobile]
sound:
                       Intel CM238 HD Audio Controller
                       nVidia GP104 High Definition Audio Controller
storage:
                       Intel HM170/QM170 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
                       Toshiba NVMe Controller
network:
  wlp2s0               Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
  enp4s0               Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2500 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
network interface:
  enp4s0               Ethernet network interface
  lo                   Loopback network interface
  wlp2s0               Ethernet network interface
disk:
  /dev/nvme0n1         Toshiba NVMe Controller
  /dev/sda             HGST HTS721010A9
partition:
  /dev/nvme0n1p1       Partition
  /dev/sda1            Partition
usb controller:
                       ASMedia ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
                       Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
bios:
                       BIOS
bridge:
                       Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1
                       Intel HM175 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
                       Intel Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16)
                       Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4
                       Intel Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
                       Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #9
                       Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #7
                       Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3
hub:
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
                       Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
                       Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
memory:
                       Main Memory
bluetooth:
                       Qualcomm Atheros Bluetooth Device
unknown:
                       FPU
                       DMA controller
                       PIC
                       Keyboard controller
                       Realtek RTS5250 PCI Express Card Reader
                       Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller
                       Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
                       Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem
                       Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus
  /dev/input/event21   Acer BisonCam, NB Pro
                       MSI EPF USB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by doing a restart of GNOME (`Alt F2` then enter `r`). Any future users with this issue should try this, or rebotting. I'm not sure why, but this should fix the issue.